# Issues in Button selection in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF MVVM. I have MainWindow.xaml here Grid is splited into two columns. Column1 hooked with MenuUserControl.xaml which has two buttons called Page1 and Page2. Column2 hooked with ContentControl which is used to display view based on button click in MenuUserControl.xaml. When clicking Page1 button its background color should change into Blue then when clicking Page2 button its background color should change into Blue and Page1 background color should change into Normal. How to achieve this in XAML?

Comment: with the MVVM pattern, you typically bind to a bool and have a ValueConverter that converts a bool to your desired color. write some code and come back and we'll help.

Comment: Can i achieve this in XAML triggers or DataTriggers?

Comment: yes you can do it that way too

Comment: There are a load of different ways to do this. If you have just 2 views then that's simple and it doesn't matter which you choose. If you have more then that quickly becomes rather more complicated and I would use a listbox. That already has a mechanism for selection. You click a row to select it and isselected becomes true. It also already has a mechanism makes the background of the selected row lightblue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lightblue colour is acceptable then this is one solution.

MainWindow has a listbox to select views and a frame to present the pages. I would usually use a contentcontrol and usercontrols rather than frame and pages but...

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page1ViewModel}">
        <local:Page1/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page2ViewModel}">
        <local:Page2/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Name="ViewSelect"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ViewChoices}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewChoice, Mode=TwoWay}"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Frame Grid.Column="1"
           Content="{Binding SelectedViewChoice.VM}"
           NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
           />
</Grid>
```

ViewChoices is a collection of ViewChoice and whichever you select will be SelectedViewChoice. The VM property is an instance of a viewmodel which ends up presented by the frame. That templates it into the associated view.

MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewChoice> ViewChoices { get; set; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ViewChoice>
    {
        new ViewChoice{ Name="Page One", VM=new Page1ViewModel()},
         new ViewChoice{ Name="Page Two", VM=new Page2ViewModel()},
    };

    private ViewChoice selectedViewChoice;

    public ViewChoice SelectedViewChoice
    {
        get { return selectedViewChoice; }
        set { selectedViewChoice = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

ViewChoice:

```
public class ViewChoice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object VM { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have two button instead of ListBox then how? selected(focused) button might be highlighted and unfocused button might be normal state.